# if else statements are not working when I add an else statement. php

Tags: php

I have an if statement with 2 more if else statements below it. However, when I add an else statement at the end of it all, the if else lines no longer work.

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Please and thank you.

The code below works fine cause the else statement is not added.

```
if(strtoupper($userData->firstName) == strtoupper($input)) {
            $firstUser = Subscriber::where('firstName', $input)->get();
            array_push($fillter, $firstUser);
            // return $fillter;
            return view('pages/results', compact('fillter'));
            
            } else if(strtoupper($userData->lastName) == strtoupper($input)) {
                    $lastUser = Subscriber::where('lastName', $input)->get();
                    array_push($fillter, $lastUser);
                    // return $fillter;
                    return view('pages/results', compact('fillter'));
                
                    } else if(strtoupper($userData->address) == strtoupper($input)) {
                        $addressUser = Subscriber::where('address', $input)->get();
                        array_push($fillter, $addressUser);
                        // return $fillter;
                        return view('pages/results', compact('fillter'));
                        
                        }
```

The code below does not work because I added the else statement.

```
if(strtoupper($userData->firstName) == strtoupper($input)) {
            $firstUser = Subscriber::where('firstName', $input)->get();
            array_push($fillter, $firstUser);
            // return $fillter;
            return view('pages/results', compact('fillter'));
            
            } else if(strtoupper($userData->lastName) == strtoupper($input)) {
                    $lastUser = Subscriber::where('lastName', $input)->get();
                    array_push($fillter, $lastUser);
                    // return $fillter;
                    return view('pages/results', compact('fillter'));
                
                    } else if(strtoupper($userData->address) == strtoupper($input)) {
                        $addressUser = Subscriber::where('address', $input)->get();
                        array_push($fillter, $addressUser);
                        // return $fillter;
                        return view('pages/results', compact('fillter'));
                        
                        } else { 
                               return view('pages/empty');
                        }
```

Comment: Does the `view()` function expect 2 arguments/parameters? ... If so, you only pass 1 in the else.

Comment: I should clarify, when I add the else statement it seems to ignore the if else statements and just runs the else statement at the bottom. 

So when I query something valid, It just takes me to the view in that else statement.

Comment: So that means none of the other previous conditions were satisfied to be true, so the else wins. We don't know the handling before the first `if`, so you might have to echo/print/print_r/var_dump some of the values before that point to see what the `$userData` and `$input` values contain.

Comment: when I var_dump $userData, I get this objects, and when I var_dump $input I get strings. However, when I dd $input, it just returns one string. 

This is my code for those variables


        $user = DB::table('subscribers')->get();
        $input = $request->input('query');

Comment: So what is the one string value to `$input`?

Comment: Whatever I query is the value of $input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The else can possibly short cut any other matches because of the return in the else block.

For example, if you search for jane, and this is not anywhere in the first `$userData` entry will go to the else: no `firstName` match, no `lastName` match, no `address` match, so then the else returns the view to no results (which also exits the foreach) and does not continue searching for other `$userData` entries.

This example should work as expected:

```
function search($request) {
    $user = DB::table('subscribers')->get();
    $input = $request->input('query');
    $fillter = [];
    
    foreach ($user as $userData) {
    
        if (strtoupper($userData->firstName) == strtoupper($input)) {
            $firstUser = Subscriber::where('firstName', $input)->get();
            array_push($fillter, $firstUser);
    
        } else if (strtoupper($userData->lastName) == strtoupper($input)) {
            $lastUser = Subscriber::where('lastName', $input)->get();
            array_push($fillter, $lastUser);
    
        } else if (strtoupper($userData->address) == strtoupper($input)) {
            $addressUser = Subscriber::where('address', $input)->get();
            array_push($fillter, $addressUser);
    
        }
    }
    
    if (!empty($fillter)) {
        return view('pages/results', compact('fillter'));
    } else {
        return view('pages/empty', compact('fillter'));
    }
}
```